# Intent does not refresh in GCMListenerService

Tags: android

I am adding functionality to receive push notifications in Android. I have added a subclass of GcmListenerService and have overriden the **onMessageReceived** method and am building a notification with action buttons. My code is as follows:

**GCMListenerService**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String message = data.getString("message");
    sendNotification(message);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PushActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("pushMessage", message);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
Intent acceptIntent = new Intent(this, GcmBroadcastReceiver.class);
acceptIntent.putExtra("pushMessage", message);
acceptIntent.putExtra("action", Constants.ACTION_ACCEPT);
acceptIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent acceptPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, acceptIntent, 0);

Intent denyIntent = new Intent(this, GcmBroadcastReceiver.class);
denyIntent.putExtra("action", Constants.ACTION_DENY);
denyIntent.putExtra("pushMessage", message);
denyIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent denyPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, denyIntent, 0);

Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Authenticator")
        .setContentText("You have initiated a transaction")
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_play, "Accept", acceptPendingIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Deny", denyPendingIntent)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The issue which I am facing is that no matter what notification I send, I am receiving the same message always when I try to use the action buttons. When I try to open the activity, the correct messages gets read. I am reading the message in the **GcmBroadcastreceiver** and it is always the same. It seems that the intent is the same and does not get recreated. Is there something I am doing wrong?